# Firebase: user is not set on the first rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Based on [this example](https://github.com/armand1m/react-firebase-authentication-medium), I wrote the following `App` component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import withFirebaseAuth from 'react-with-firebase-auth'
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

import './common.css'
import './fonts.css'
import NotSignedIn from './NotSignedIn/NotSignedIn'

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class App extends Component {
  render = () => {
    const {
      user,
      //signOut,
      signInWithGoogle,
    } = this.props;
    return user ? <p>Hello, {user.displayName}</p> : <NotSignedIn signIn={signInWithGoogle}/>;
  }
}

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();

const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

For some reason, if I refresh the page when the user is signed in, the `<NotSignedIn>` component is momentarily rendered, and only then the page is re-rendered and the "Hello [etc.]" message appears. Why does this happen and how do I fix this, so that `user` would be correctly set on the first rendering?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a loader in `state`.
2. In the authentication callback, update `user` in the state to render correct component based on condition.

This way you can get rid of the **not logged in** component and show a **loading** component on each page refresh.

3. Optional - Once the auth is completed, store user id in cookie or localstorage and pull data from there to avoid showing loading all the time.

With the above step, you can get rid of **loading** component as well, and make your app load data quicker.

Here's an example with 1st & 2nd point in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-login-non-login-user-8pljl?file=/src/App.js:493-514

Comment: Could you please explain why what I observe happens in the first place?

Comment: when you land on the page, user in state is null and loading is true so it shows loading.. 2 secs later user state has a value and loading is false so the dashboard component is renderd. if the loading is false and user Id is null, then loggedin component will be rendered.. you can debug into the code to know more

Comment: Why is it null at the beginning?